# trouble calling different header.php for home.php

Tags: templates, headers, custom-header

I'm making a site that uses the same `header.php` for all pages except the blog/`home.php`. For this, I've created `blog-header.php` and am attempting to call it using the following:

`<?php if( is_page(15) ) {
echo get_template_part( 'blog', 'header' );}
else {
echo get_header(); } ?>`

However, it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas on why that may be? (It should be noted that this is my first attempt at anything like this, and what I have has been pieced together from various forum posts and tutorials.)

blog-header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
        <meta name="generator" content="Wordpress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback url'); ?>" />
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/favicon.ico" />
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>



<body>
        <div id="blog-header">
                <div class="logo">
                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="Urban Palate logo" id="logo" /></a>
                </div><!-- end logo -->
                <nav>
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="?page_id=7"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/about.png" alt="Urban Palate intro" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="?page_id=12"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/portfolio.png" alt="Urban Palate portfolio" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="?page_id=15"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/blog.png" alt="Urban Palate blog" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="?page_id=10"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/contact.png" alt="Urban Palate contact" /></a></li>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
        </div><!-- end blog-header -->
```

(Unfortunately, the site isn't live yet otherwise I'd provide a link.)

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the file header-bog.php and using `<?php get_header( 'blog');?>` works perfectly.